# How does Base Attack Bonus work, exactly? As in, how do I understand the formatting of the Base Attack Bonus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat

So everywhere I'm looking I'm seeing BAB bonuses beyond a certain level start being formatted as such +10/+5 at level 10. I understand that once you reach a +6 BAB you get an extra attack as well as at +11, but what are the second and third numbers for? and why are they divided if the amount of attacks I get is always based on the first number?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I think this question has already been asked and answered [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/27839/8610). (Click that red *here* to follow the link.) If that answers this question, add a comment saying so, and someone will mark this as a duplicate. If that doesn't, please update this question to reflect what new information needs to be covered. Thank you for participating and have fun.

Comment: Okay, so if I'm reading this correctly, the first number (+10) applies to my first attack, and the second attack would only have the BAB of the second number, (+5?) If so, then yeah, this helped!

Comment: That sounds right.

Comment: @NoivernEvo: remember, too, that BAB from multiple sources (typically classes) stack, so if you have +4 from Fighter, +4 from Rogue, and +4 from Bard, you have a +12/+7/+2 BAB. Similarly, if you've got +6/+1 from Cleric and +6/+1 from Barbarian, you've got a +12/+7/+2, not a +12/+2. I've got a player who just started in my campaign that took a while to get that straight.